# MacBook Pro sometimes freezes after waking from sleep

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, sleep-wake, performance

Since I updated to Yosemite after it was released my MacBook Pro (Mid 2012 2.5 GHz Intel Core i5) sometimes freezes for several minutes after waking it from sleep mode. It does not happen every time my mac is woken up and I have not noticed any other performance issues. When it does freeze, it gets stuck on the login screen and I cannot type or move the mouse for a few minutes, then it will go back to normal allowing me to enter my password and it works fine from there.

Any ideas on what could be causing this issue and how to fix it? Thanks!

Comment: I have the same issue, I've been looking for a solution forever now...
[![enter image description here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/lND5S.png)](http://i.stack.imgur.com/lND5S.png)

Answer (score 1):

This is an often reported problem (with Yosemite) that has been fixed recently.

As of OS X 10.10.4, released yesterday, Apple reinstated mDNSResponder to handle DNS processes previously assigned to discoveryd since the debut of OS X 10.10 Yosemite.

For more information see: http://appleinsider.com/articles/15/05/26/latest-os-x-beta-ditches-buggy-discoveryd-dns-service-replaced-with-mdnsresponder

The best way to fix this problem is to update to 10.10.4.

Comment: Unfortunately, this did not resolve the issue.  I have updated to 10.10.4, but my laptop still intermittently freezes when being woken up.